# Upload image to imgur via API - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to upload an image to imgur via their API and i'm receiving an error 400.

```
{"data":{"error":"Invalid URL (Array)","request":"\/3\/image","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":400}
```

My code:

```
  const submitForm = async (event, imageFile) => {
    axios.post(
      "https://api.imgur.com/3/image",
      { image: imageFile, type: "file" },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.REACT_APP_IMGUR_CLIENT_ID}`,
        },
      }
    );
  };
```

When printing "imageFile":

```
File {
name: "1545572599598.jpg", 
lastModified: 1545573667488, 
lastModifiedDate: Sun Dec 23 2018 16:01:07 GMT+0200, 
webkitRelativePath: "", 
size: 291376, …
}
```

searched like everywhere on the internet.

somone have seen that before?

Thanks

Comment: also tried to use their npm with not sucess.

Comment: maybe this is the answer you look for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309644/http-failure-response-for-https-api-imgur-com-3-image

Comment: sorry, I meant this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907282/imgur-api-400-error

Comment: @tomerraitz I saw this post, but the owner of the post didnt understood the solution, either I'm hehehe